# Android/OkHttp Get source code

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp

i want to get the source code of this page, "http://wankil.fr/dons", and print it in the TextView, but nothing is printed i don't know why, need some help please.

On this code, i want to get the name of the donater, and the comment of every donation. This information are in code source but nothing is printed on my TextView just for the test, i don't understand why...

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView                        vue;
private Vector<Vector<String>>          listDons = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
private List<HashMap<String, String>>   listHash = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private URL                             url;
private OkHttpClient                    client = new OkHttpClient();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vue = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        this.createNewDonation("Raphael T.", "Vous etes trop fort");
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyString", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
                listHash,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[]{"text1", "text2"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        vue.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

public String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    Log.d("isOnline", "I'm in");
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

public void printText(View v) {
    try {
        Log.d("Here", "I'm in");
        if (this.isOnline() == true) {
            Log.d("Status:", "I'm online");
            String str;
            str = this.run("http://wankil.fr/dons");
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(str);
            //this.createNewDonation(str.substring(0, 10), str.substring(10, 20));
        } else
            Log.d("Status:", "I'm not online");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void     createNewDonation(String text1, String text2){
    try {
        StringBuilder newDons = new StringBuilder();
        Vector<String> tmp = new Vector<String>();
        HashMap<String, String> element = new HashMap<>();

        tmp.add(text1);
        tmp.add(text2);
        listDons.add(tmp);
        element.put("text1", listDons.get(0).get(0));
        element.put("text2", listDons.get(0).get(1));
        listHash.add(element);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

}

Error:

```
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
07-11 15:49:48.696    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:273)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dot.wankilapp.Main.run(Main.java:78)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dot.wankilapp.Main.printText(Main.java:96)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-11 15:49:48.697    8109-8109/com.dot.wankilapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: This is not going to be a 1 step answer. YOu want to get the name of the donater, and the comment of every donation: What line is that supposed to happen on?
Also: Do not create global private parameters if they are only used local in a function: listDons vector can be local to createNewDonation or better not created at all: Why add something in a vector to retrieve it from there at once, and not use it anywhere else. Look through your code and take out not used parts please.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I know, I just started,the Android/Java code yesterday, i know who to code in `C/C++` but i'm a noob in Java, so i don't know opti thing, and it's just a "Test" project for improve my skill in this langage. And the name and the comment of the donater is between tag html, the next step is to learn parsing in Java. Thank you for your response.

Comment: You need to execute your network call on a different thread.

Comment: Thank you so much, It's two days that I am above !!!